# Error in Eclipse launch configuration: GrammaticalStructure.1 references non-existing project begins

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a java project following these steps:

```
1.File->java project
2. Created the package.
3. Created the main class.
```

Wrote the simple program to print hello world

```
 package misc;
 public class MyMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
           }
     }
```

but I get the error when I run the program

```
Launch configuration GrammaticalStructure.1 references non-existing project begins.
```

Could you please let me know what can be the reason for it?

Comment: How exactly did you run it? You should right-click on the source file and select "Run As -> Java Application".

Comment: Thanks Francis, it worked when i run it as java application. I was running the pressing green run button.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Please try to run it by right-clicking on your source file and select:  "Run As -> Java Application".

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on your project and select "Run As"->Run Configurations.you can edit the "Main class"

Comment: How is that better than the already accepted answer ? (posted 6 months before…)

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on "src" folder of your project then "Run As"->"Run Configurations" then change the "Main class" option with the name same as your driving code name.
This happens because there may exist more than one main classes in the same project may be due to some testing requirement or by mistake.

Comment: This answer is already posted 2 years ago? What value does this add?

Comment: @EWit I think this particular answer includes more info that any of the other answers. Even if it is not much, there clearly seems to be some added value to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem even recently. None of the above answers helped. There was still some reference to the older compiled code configuration. 
I even tried closing & opening the project, setting Build Automatically option & Clean. None worked.

Hence you need to go to Run Configurations & delete the previous configuration. This will remove previous references of the configuration. 
Create a new Configuration, select the Project & Main class & then Run. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. Trying to run it by selecting the `Run as` button didn't work for me. I think an old reference to an old project kept blocking the run.

What I've done is that I disconnected all old projects and recreated the new one again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The best solution I found to solve this was to remove the existing project from the Eclipse bar. After that, I haven't experienced the problem anymore.
I hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Haha, the cause is it can only be run on a PC, no way on a server.

Nick...

Comment: That doesn't seem to square with the rest of the answers, including the accepted answer.